# THE COUNTER CREATED USING JAVASCRIPT NOT WORKING

Tags: javascript

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <script>
            let counter= 0;
            function count() {
                counter++;
                document.querySelector('#counter').innerHTML= counter;
            }
        </script>
        <title>My Webpage</title>
        </head>
        <body>
           <h1 id="counter">0</h1>
           <button onlclick="count()">Click Here!</button>
        </body>
    </html>
```

when i am running it on internet explorer and also on an online IDE for html the page displays 0 and click here but when i click on the button the page remains the same and the 0 not changes to 1.
Please help what changes can i make

Comment: Try updating your button to: `<button onclick="count()">Click Here!</button>` and change your `count()` function to include `document.getElementById('#counter').innerHTML= counter;`.

Comment: typo `onlclick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in `onclick`, here is the working version.

```js
let counter = 0;

function count() {
  counter++;
  document.querySelector('#counter').innerHTML = counter;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Webpage</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="counter">0</h1>
  <button onclick="count()">Click Here!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sorry it was fault on my behalf  extremely sorry